# how to run the dialog command with proccess

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process, dialog

Please look on my code – ( bash script )

I want to display both dialogs on the screen on the same time,

one dialog display the:

**tail –f from - /var/log/proccess1.log**  ,

and the second dialog display the:

**tail –f from the file - /var/log/proccess2.log**

but the sad fact is that I can display only one dialog and not both dialogs ( because when I run the first dialog , the second dialog will activate only if the first dialog will killed )

So I create process on the second dialog **( ….. ) &**    , in order to display both dialogs

But …. the second dialog create process number but not create the second dialog GUI , ( seems that when we create dialog with process , the process not send the dialog to standard output )

So how to  run the second dialog with process but send the dialog GUI to screen ? , or other solution in order to display both dialogs on screen

**My code**

```
     #!/bin/bash

     # this dialog will locate the tail box on the top of the screen
     dialog --begin 15 10  --tailbox   /var/log/proccess1.log  13 125 


     # this dialog will locate the tail box down in the screen
     ( dialog --begin 37 10  --tailbox   /var/log/proccess2.log    13 125 ) &
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the first time I deal with `dialog`. Reading in the man page, I think this is what you are after:

```
#!/bin/bash

# this dialog will locate the tail box on the top of the screen
dialog --keep-window --begin 15 10  --tailboxbg  /var/log/syslog 13 125 \
       --and-widget  --begin 37 10  --tailbox    /var/log/dmesg  13 125
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
dialog --keep-window --begin 0 0 --tailboxbg /var/log/process1.log 20 110 \
  --and-widget --keep-window --begin 0 120 --tailboxbg /var/log/process2.log 20 110 \
  --and-widget --begin 21 100 --msgbox "Press Enter to exit." 5 25
```

Adjust the numbers to fit your need. I had to use the `msgbox` to keep `dialog` alive.

Comment: Confirming that this works, but you have to keep the `--msgbox` doesn't work w/o that.

Answer (score 1):

How about making this in `screen` session? Two split windows with each tailbox inside...

I'm thinking about (this is a `.screenrc` config file):

```
startup_message off
screen dialog --begin 10 10  --tailbox   /var/log/proccess1.log  13 125
split
focus down
screen dialog --begin 10 10  --tailbox   /var/log/proccess2.log  13 125
```

To run, use: `screen -c screenrcfile`

HTH, Cheers

Comment: screen session isnt good for me , I want to implemned the case as described in my question

Comment: why this case is so complicated ? , must be solution here

Comment: You can also chain widgets but afaik it's not possible to have two at a same time. Try this, maybe it will suite your needs:
    `dialog --begin 10 10 --tailbox /var/log/proccess1.log 13 125 --and-widget --begin 25 10 --tailbox /var/log/proccess2.log 13 125`

Comment: is there a solution for that? im looking for the same thing.