# Echo choices to Choice Menu to run program directly from CommandLine

Tags: bash, powershell

When I run a specific program with choices

1. Do this
2. Do that
3. Do something else

And eventual sub-choices
Enter website:
Enter credentials:

I want to do the following

`echo {choice} | echo {choice2} | echo {choice3} | program`

However this is not working. Is there an alternative to bypass the choice menu's to directly execute commando's from the CommandLine. Eventually with PowerShell/CMD and Bash as well?

Update: For the people who do not understand what I want let me explain it with the example below:

If I execute example.sh I get a choice menu and have to manually enter the choice to get something. This is not what I want, because I do not want to provide user-input this way.

I don't know if there is an option to provide user-input by using echo. But that is my question.

I want to echo the choices towards the example.sh so it will execute the choice directly without prompting me with the user-choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. This was due wrong manipulation of the stdin.

This can be done with some programs and does not work for every program.

Examples are:

```
printf "command1\ncommand2\ncommand3" | commandyouwanttoexecute
```

A more cleaner way to read this and not to use the \n functions:

```
(echo command1; echo command2; echo command3;) | cat | commandyouwantoexecute
```

The last way to do this is using multiple lines:

```
cat <<EOF | commandyouwanttoexecute
command1
command2
...
EOF
```

For Windows on CMD or PowerShell it can be done by encapsulation of the echo commands and using && to execute multiple echo commands:

```
(echo "test" && echo "test") | powershell
```

Answer (score 1):

> Eventually with PowerShell/CMD and Bash as well?

These are sufficiently different that you won't find a sensible thing that you'd do in both environments, so let's focus on what works on bash, as this is not the windows systems programming SE.

> I want to do the following
>
> `echo {choice} | echo {choice2} | echo {choice3} | program`

You won't, because that's not how `echo` nor `|` work.

You want to use the `select` bash built-in as described in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1716) answer, or the `dialog` program as illustrated e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167332/how-to-run-the-dialog-command-with-proccess).

Neither are an option for powershell. I'm sure powershell has its own ways of making a multiple choice prompt.

Comment: Well I don't want to make a multiple choice prompt. I want to execute it directly from the commandline instead of executing the program, entering the choices, etc.

Comment: *what* do you want to execute? I'm very confused now!

Comment: It's an example: I have example.sh which if I execute manually provides me with a choice list and asks for user-input for the choice. Then if I input the choice I get the provided content. (for example console-output back). But what I want to do is that I get the console-output immediately by providing the choice in the CLI . See it as `echo "2" | example.sh` but this does not work. I get mostly incorrect choice because the pipe does not correctly handle it.

Comment: ah, so maybe the selection program doesn't read from the  standard input (which is what you can interact by piping `|` things into the program), but directly reads keyboard input, in which case this won't work. It really is up to your `example.sh` though, which we don't know!